# Как увидеть hello world на экране, запустив exe файл java?

Tags: java

В ide вывод на экран сообщений через System.out.println() работает.
А если скомпилировать exe файл из jar с тем же кодом, то ничего не выводится. Пробовал задержку ставить, не помогает. В коде есть удаление файлов, оно выполняется, а вот вывод на экран нет.

Comment: а зачем jar в exe ?

Comment: вывод на какой экран? встроенный консоль на компе по идее должно запустится . А если имеется ввиду как приложение на экран то это далеко от простого S.o.p() я настольное приложение создавал через javaFX 3 года назад сейчас возможно что то другое используется

Comment: jar в ехе чтобы была программа для запуска на компьютерах. Она выполняет операции с файлами определенные. А что?

Comment: Вывод на экран должен быть после апуска exe файла. Пользователь запускает программу, видит информационное сообщение, ожидает когда нужные файлы обновятся, после завершения продолжает работу.

Comment: exe файл нужен, чтобы скрыть код. Декомпилировать никто не будет. Сейчас этот код в bat файле есть. Переделываю на java для того чтобы скрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам диалоговое окно подойдет?

Можно заменить все `System.out.println(txt)`
на `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, txt);`

---

Или надо что бы в cmd?